# Why does `chroot` operation result in error: "bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied"?

Tags: bash, chroot, jails

Why does `chroot` operation result in error: "`bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied`"?

I've been testing `chroot` for learning purposes, and have encountered the following error, when executing `/bin/bash`:

```
nlykkei@debian:~$ id
uid=1000(nlykkei) gid=1000(nlykkei) groups=1000(nlykkei),27(sudo)
nlykkei@debian:~$ sudo chroot --userspec nlykkei:root --groups sudo / /bin/bash
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
nlykkei@debian:/$ id
uid=1000(nlykkei) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),27(sudo)
```

It seems like `/bin/bash` is attempting to access root's `.bashrc` instead of `nlykkei`'s?

Furthermore, I cannot make `NEWROOT` e.g. `~` and execute `/bin/bash` by creating `~/bin/bash` (copy):

```
nlykkei@debian:~$ ls -la ~/bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nlykkei nlykkei 1168776 Sep 23 10:49 /home/nlykkei/bin/bash
nlykkei@debian:~$ sudo chroot --userspec nlykkei:root --groups sudo /home/nlykkei/ /bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

Any ways to resolve these issues?

```
nlykkei@debian:~$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-5 (2019-06-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `--userspec` to `chroot` is not the same thing as running `su - user` inside the chroot environment; i.e. the home directory is still that of root i.e. `/root` which is why `bash` is trying to read `/root/.bashrc` which is not allowed for non-root users.

Your second problem is probably due to not having included all the necessary shared libraries in the chroot environment. From the `chroot` info document:

> If you want to use a dynamically linked executable, say ‘bash’, then
>   first run ‘ldd bash’ to see what shared objects it needs.  Then, in
>   addition to copying the actual binary, also copy the listed files to
>   the required positions under your intended new root directory. 
>   Finally, if the executable requires any other files (e.g., data,
>   state, device files), copy them into place, too.

Comment: should I instead set `HOME` to `/home/nlykkei` before `chroot`, or what is your suggestion?

Comment: You would have to set it after the `sudo` and before the `chroot`. Perhaps a better alternative is `sudo chroot /home/nlykkei su - nlykkei` (doing `chroot /` is kind of pointless, now I look at it again).